# Quickest way to install Node.js on Raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, installation, raspberry-pi

I have installed node.js on about 9 pis now. 
The fact that the make command takes about 4 hours destroys my soul a little bit every time.

I have tried to run the command over multiple jobs with 'make -j $(nproc)' although it only took 2 hours, the make install command now takes like 2 hours.

My question is.
Is there a way to get the latest version of node.js on the raspberry pi in under an hour?

i have checked out cross compiling, but it seems very complicated. Specially seeing as i have a windows machine.

Thanks

Comment: `wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.3.2/node-v4.3.2-linux-armv6l.tar.gz 
tar -xvf node-v4.3.2-linux-armv6l.tar.gz 
cd node-v4.3.2-linux-armv6l` is what I used. I got it from the tutorial at [this website](https://blog.wia.io/installing-node-js-on-a-raspberry-pi-3)

Comment: though if you want the latest version I can remember (`7.10`) then you should change all instalces of `v4.3.2` to `v7.10.0` and it should work as well. (I can't check as my raspberry pi is at my house)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to compile it from source on the actual PI, you just download the tar archive, unzip it and you are good to go!